# PHP check date & time interval in two different date and time

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have date from date `27-11-2021` and to date `28-11-2021` for rent request of an item take example of like car for rent. I need the car for rent on above date. And this car be already rented on

On online car renting service i'm creating a request for car rent on following date.

`From - 27-11-2021` and `To - 29-11-2021`

And this car may be already rented on different dates. Take examples of some date -

`From - 25-11-2021` and `To - 26-11-2021`

`From - 27-11-2021` and `To - 28-11-2021`

`From - 26-11-2021` and `To - 27-11-2021`

So i need to compare and find availability of that car is that available on certain date period or not!

And in one another case if there are many car of same variant if one car is not available then how we will check for another car is available or not?

I need a idea on this in `php`

Comment: You're basically searching for a range. Use two variables for the reserved date $startDate and $endDate, and two variables for the search date $startSearch and $endSearch. Then check `if ($startSearch <= $endDate && $startSearch >= $startDate || $endSearch <= $endDate && $endSearch >= $startDate) { /* car already reaerved */ }` either the search date falls somewhere within the reserved range or the end date falls somewhere within the reserved range, in those cases the dates overlap and a reservation is not possible.

Comment: but car may be reserved for many different date range so i need to check inside loop through all reserved date range?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

//Requested from and to date

$fromDate = strtotime('27-11-2021');
$toDate = strtotime('29-11-2021');

//Note: You have to loop from here for different car variant
//Booked details for car 1 *as per example

$carBookedDetailsArray = array(
    0 => array(
        'bookingFromDate' => '25-11-2021',
        'bookingToDate' => '26-11-2021'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'bookingFromDate' => '27-11-2021',
        'bookingToDate' => '28-11-2021'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'bookingFromDate' => '26-11-2021',
        'bookingToDate' => '27-11-2021'
    ),
);

$bookingFromDate = "";
$bookingToDate = "";
$bookedFlag=0;

for ($i=0; $i <count($carBookedDetailsArray) ; $i++) { 

    $bookingFromDate = strtotime($carBookedDetailsArray[$i]['bookingFromDate']);
    $bookingToDate = strtotime($carBookedDetailsArray[$i]['bookingToDate']);

    if (($fromDate < $bookingFromDate && $toDate < $bookingFromDate) || ($fromDate > $bookingToDate && $toDate > $bookingToDate)){
        echo "Booking Success for Car 1 form ".date('d-m-Y',$fromDate)." to ".date('d-m-Y',$toDate); 
        $bookedFlag=1;
        break;
    }
    
}

if($bookedFlag==0){
    echo "Car 1 is not availble for your requested time";
}

//Note: You have to loop to here for different car variant
```